# Windows.h with SQLite visual c++ error

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, sqlite

I have just started windows application programming 2 days ago.. I am using VC++ and it is having some issues which I am unable to figure out.
When i send proper arguments to the function below, it displays everything properly but it doesn't save the insert query to the DB.

Here is the statement:

```
INSERT INTO BOOKS(ID,USERNAME,ISSUER,RETURNED) VALUES(1,'xyz','xyz',0);
```

Here is the table creation statement of sqlite:

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BOOKS("  \
     "ID INT PRIMARY KEY    NOT NULL," \
     "BOOKNAME           TEXT    NOT NULL," \
     "ISSUER            TEXT     NOT NULL," \
     "RETURNED        INT);";
```

Here is the function:

```
using namespace std;
int WriteToDB(sqlite3 *,const char [],wchar_t *,HWND *);

int WriteToDB(sqlite3 *_db,const char _query[],wchar_t *ermsg,HWND *hw)
{
    sqlite3_stmt *insertStmt;
    MessageBox(*hw,L"Creating insert statement",L"INFO",MB_OK);

    if(sqlite3_prepare(_db, _query, 400,&insertStmt, NULL))
    MessageBox(*hw,L"Prepared!",L"Info",MB_OK);

    MessageBox(*hw,L"Stepping into insert statement",L"INFO",MB_OK);
    MessageBox(*hw,(LPWSTR)_query,L"Input",MB_OK);

    if (sqlite3_step(insertStmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        wcscpy(ermsg,CharToWChar("Didn't Insert Item! Please check statement or DataBase!!"));
        return 0;
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(insertStmt);
    return 1;
```

}

EDIT: Here is the new error i got:

In SQLite,

```
near "I": Syntax Error
```

This Statement:

```
INSERT INTO BOOKS(ID,BOOKNAME,ISSUER,RETURNED) VALUES(1,'xyz','xyz',0);
```

Comment: no error just doesn't save... that is Didn't insert item pops up.

Comment: Post `sql` definition and `WriteToDB` call.

Answer (score 1):

Mistake here:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare(_db, _query, 400,&insertStmt, NULL)) //...
```

Should be:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare(_db, _query, 400,&insertStmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) //...
```

Because `#define SQLITE_OK 0  /* Successful result */`, your previous condition was opposite to pretended one.

Advice: instead of merging data in SQL statement, consider using parameters and [`sqlite3_bind_*`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) interfaces.

EDIT:

Using `sqlite3_prepare_v2` is recommended over `sqlite3_prepare`. Using such, you can easily have information on error cause with `sqlite3_errmsg`:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare(_db, _query, 400,&insertStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    MessageBox(*hw,L"Prepared!",L"Info",MB_OK);
} else {
    MessageBox(*hw, sqlite3_errmsg16(_db), L"Error", MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: OK... that's where the problem is... i did as u said and when i ran it, "Prepared" isn't showing on screen... guess there is something wrong there... need help...

Comment: umm could u elaborate a bit to me? i m so lost :/

Comment: That would force you to redesign your function, but is safer to use `INSERT INTO BOOKS(ID,USERNAME,ISSUER,RETURNED) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);` and before `sqlite3_step` use `sqlite3_bind_int(insertStmt, 1, 1); sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 2, "xyz", -1,  SQLITE_STATIC); ...`

Comment: but i need that the statement like it is :/

Comment: OK, that was just one advice! Keep going to find real problem!

Comment: @electruxenergy Show us the int value returned by sqlite3_prepare, then.